# How can I fire a vue method directly within div element

Tags: vue.js

I am using blade for controlling some parts of the html with conditional rendering. For example if laravel session `login` exists then render a div that fires a vue method. In this way I will be able to open a login modal. Actually right now I am using vue-js-modal and generally open modals with `$modal.show('login-modal')`.

What I am looking for is something like:

```
@if( session('openLogin') )
    <div v-directly-run="$modal.show('login-modal')"></div>
@endif
```

This is actually a simple task, perhaps I am overseeing something. Is there a convenient way for this or have I to create a custom (@on @emit) event?

Comment: You could use a data-attribute holding the name of the function to execute on `mounted()`, and inside `mounted()`, check for the presence and content of that attribute. Example: `data-mounted="showModal"` and in `mounted() { if (this.dataset.mounted && typeof this[this.dataset.mounted] === 'function') { this[this.dataset.mounted](); }}`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Right now I am storing function names in laravel session where I then receive from front end and execute. But I wonder if there is another way than this?

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't this work `<div :dummy="$modal.show('login-modal')"></div>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you created a method and then just do?:

```
@if( session('openLogin') )
     <div>{{method()}}</div>
@endif
```

This should execute the method when it gets rendered.